# Base64 + sha256 not giving expected result

Tags: php

I need to figure out why I get the wrong results, here is the thing:

**Expected result**

Mu0FBjARVsNyDiixnKqyLCCqVunTSPQFCMnOwGQsIWliY2Jh

**Current Result**

MzJlZDA1MDYzMDExNTZjMzcyMGUyOGIxOWNhYWIyMmMyMGFhNTZlOWQzNDhmNDA1MDhjOWNlYzA2NDJjMjE2OQ==

**The code I'm using (php)**

```
echo base64_encode(hash("sha256", $pass.$salt'));
```

This site http://www.insidepro.com/hashes.php giveme a preety closer result

sha256($pass.$salt) => Mu0FBjARVsNyDiixnKqyLCCqVunTSPQFCMnOwGQsIWk=

you can find (in the site, near the result field) a [1], that means "Hash in Base64"

the thing is... I can't even get the sites result

---

**EDIT (Thanks Jon)**

now the code goes like this

```
echo base64_encode(hash("sha256", $pass.$salt', true));
```

I'm getting the same result as in the site

---

the problem now is the difference between the two results

```
actual result   : Mu0FBjARVsNyDiixnKqyLCCqVunTSPQFCMnOwGQsIWk=
expected result : Mu0FBjARVsNyDiixnKqyLCCqVunTSPQFCMnOwGQsIWliY2Jh
```

Comment: Your expected result is only 192 bits, so it's smaller than the output of SHA-256 can possibly be. Your actual result looks completely plausible.

Comment: I hope you're not using this to store passwords. Don't make new stuff ([Ex1](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why), [Ex2](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)), stick (if you can) to [what's been made to do this](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: I haven't developed the system, just using it, but the documentations was realy poor (or perhaps I don't have enough knowledge).

Comment: Your code contains a quote in `$pass.$salt'` remove it. Otherwise, it will throw an error. `echo base64_encode(hash("sha256", $pass.$salt, true));` or add one `'$pass.$salt'` --- Yet I must add, that with or without those quotes, it will produce different results.

Comment: What is the salt? "liY2Jh"? If someone made this they are probably manipulating the result somehow also.

Comment: the salt is not "liY2Jh". I think the way you do. Must be another step...

Answer (score 2):

[`hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) returns a *hex-encoded string* of its output by default, while you are expecting it to return raw bytes. Luckily it accepts a third argument; set it to `true` like this:

```
echo base64_encode(hash("sha256", $pass.$salt', true));
```

Comment: Thanks Jon that get me closer, now I' got the same result as in the other site. the thing now is the minimal diference between the results

Comment: @Manuel: Your expected result is 48 chars long, which means you  encoded 48 * 3 / 4 = 36 bytes. Since the output of sha256 is always 32 bytes long that doesn't add up. You have made a mistake somewhere in the question text. Where did you get the expected result from? You have involved 4 more bytes of data in its calculation, but I have no idea where they came from.

Comment: this is the token suposed to get after login in a webservise. If the sha256 long adds somethig or not is not the problem I think. I don't know where the 4 more bytes came from, may be the $salt actualy has 4 characters long

Comment: What I thought was a stupid thing. The 4 characters noting have to do with the 4 bytes

Comment: Sidenote: It should read as `echo base64_encode(hash("sha256", $pass.$salt, true));` --- There's a quote in `$salt'` which will throw an error. Or to add one `'$pass.$salt'` --- Not certain if there's one too many or one missing, because in testing it, they both produced different results. So, it's hard to say for certain. Your views on this Jon?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: That quote is an obvious error but the code would not compile with it, so I disregarded it entirely (the OP's code seems to compile). It should be removed, as adding another single quote would not substitute the values of the variables.