# Add array values from array to array values

Tags: php, arrays

`$prices` has the following values

```
Array
(
    [0] => 824.2776
    [1] => 1586.5128
    [2] => 2277.8424
    [3] => 2902.698
    [4] => 3465.5112
    [5] => 3957.4188

)
```

I also have some voucher codes in `$vArray` which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [voucher1] => 30
    [voucher2] => 40

)
```

I would like to create prices which have a percentage subtracted. In this case 30% and 40% ... just not sure how.

```
 foreach($prices as $price){
    foreach($vArray as $key => $value){
        $prices[] = ($value / $price) * 100;
    }
  }
```

The above foreach is creating these additional array items in `$prices`

```
[6] => 3.6395505591805
[7] => 1.8909396759988
[8] => 1.3170358054622
[9] => 1.0335212274925
[10] => 0.86567315090484
[11] => 0.75806988130748
```

Comment: Should the `$prices` array be modified in some way or do you want a new array to be created? Please supply an example of what result you want.

Comment: I would like to have the original prices as well as the new prices with each percentage subtracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prices = [
    100,
    824.2776,
    1586.5128,
    2277.8424,
    2902.698,
    3465.5112,
    3957.4188
];

$vArray = [
    'voucher1' => 30,
    'voucher2' => 40,
];

foreach ($prices as $price) {
    foreach ($vArray as $voucherId => $percentage){
        $prices[] = $price * (1 - ($percentage / 100));
    }
}

print_r($prices);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 824.2776
    [2] => 1586.5128
    [3] => 2277.8424
    [4] => 2902.698
    [5] => 3465.5112
    [6] => 3957.4188
    [7] => 70
    [8] => 60
    [9] => 576.99432
    [10] => 494.56656
      ...
    [20] => 2374.45128
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create the array the way I want to in my question? Then when someone buys something, I can just check if his prices are in the array. Which will be available if the user activates a voucher or not.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. Edit coming up.

Comment: I've been having that problem lately ... :(

Comment: Oh, tough luck. A tip may be, when asking a question on SO, to divide  your question into paragraphs like 'Current code', 'Current result', 'Expected result', [here is one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263520/base64-sha256-not-giving-expected-result).

Comment: Then again, it was just the expected result part I had a problem with here. Did I get it right this time, by the way? (See edit) :-P

Comment: :) 1 sec ... let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72092/discussion-between-mhall-and-ciprian).